# How do I use IIOMetadata to find the GPS metadata in a jpeg image?

Tags: java, metadata, javax.imageio

I'm trying to find the GPS Metadata in an image file. I know it's there, because I can see it when I choose Get Info in the finder. But when I parse through all the Metadata, I don't see it. Here are the two methods I use to parse the data:

```
private static void readMetaData(final File filePath, final String ext) throws IOException {
  try (ImageInputStream inputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(filePath)) {
    final Iterator<ImageReader> imageReadersByFormatName = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName(ext);
    int rdrCount = 0;
    while (imageReadersByFormatName.hasNext()) {
      System.out.printf("Using reader %d%n", rdrCount++);
      ImageReader imageReader = imageReadersByFormatName.next();

      imageReader.setInput(inputStream, true, false);

      // read metadata of first image
      IIOMetadata metadata = imageReader.getImageMetadata(0);
      System.out.printf("Metadata of %s%n", metadata.getClass());
      String[] formatNames = metadata.getMetadataFormatNames();
      System.out.printf("Formats: %d%n", formatNames.length);
      int fIndex = 0;
      for (String formatName : formatNames) {
        System.out.printf("Format %d of %d %s:%n", ++fIndex, formatNames.length, formatName);

        IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) metadata.getAsTree(formatName);
        printChildren(root, "");
      }
      String[] extraFormats = metadata.getExtraMetadataFormatNames();
      if (extraFormats != null) {
        int index = 0;
        for (String extraFormat : extraFormats) {
          System.out.printf("Extra format %s (%d of %d)%n",
              extraFormat, index++, extraFormats.length);
          IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) metadata.getAsTree(extraFormat);
          printChildren(root, "");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

private static void printChildren(IIOMetadataNode node, String indent) {
  String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
  indent += '/' + nodeName;
  final NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
  int childCount = childNodes.getLength();
  for (int n = 0; n < childCount; ++n) {
    IIOMetadataNode child = (IIOMetadataNode) childNodes.item(n);
    String childName = child.getNodeName();
    // child.getNodeValue() and child.getPrefix() always return null
    NamedNodeMap attributes = child.getAttributes();
    int aLength = attributes.getLength();
    for (int a = 0; a < aLength; ++a) {
      Node item = attributes.item(a);
      final String itemName = item.getNodeName();
      System.out.printf("  [%s/%s] %s = %s%n",
          indent, childName, itemName, child.getAttribute(itemName));
    }
    printChildren(child, indent);
  }
}
```

I realize there are libraries out there that will parse the metadata for me, but this is part of a larger effort to understand the metadata, and the libraries I've tried hide the details from me.

Here is the metadata that I get:

```
Using reader 0
Metadata of class com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGMetadata
Formats: 2
Format 1 of 2 javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0:
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/JPEGvariety/app0JFIF] majorVersion = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/JPEGvariety/app0JFIF] minorVersion = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/JPEGvariety/app0JFIF] resUnits = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/JPEGvariety/app0JFIF] Xdensity = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/JPEGvariety/app0JFIF] Ydensity = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/JPEGvariety/app0JFIF] thumbWidth = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/JPEGvariety/app0JFIF] thumbHeight = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/unknown] MarkerTag = 225
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dqt/dqtable] elementPrecision = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dqt/dqtable] qtableId = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dqt/dqtable] elementPrecision = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dqt/dqtable] qtableId = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof] process = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof] samplePrecision = 8
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof] numLines = 2592
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof] samplesPerLine = 1944
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof] numFrameComponents = 3
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] componentId = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] HsamplingFactor = 2
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] VsamplingFactor = 2
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] QtableSelector = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] componentId = 2
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] HsamplingFactor = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] VsamplingFactor = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] QtableSelector = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] componentId = 3
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] HsamplingFactor = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] VsamplingFactor = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sof/componentSpec] QtableSelector = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dht/dhtable] class = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dht/dhtable] htableId = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dht/dhtable] class = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dht/dhtable] htableId = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dht/dhtable] class = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dht/dhtable] htableId = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dht/dhtable] class = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/dht/dhtable] htableId = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos] numScanComponents = 3
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos] startSpectralSelection = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos] endSpectralSelection = 63
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos] approxHigh = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos] approxLow = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos/scanComponentSpec] componentSelector = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos/scanComponentSpec] dcHuffTable = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos/scanComponentSpec] acHuffTable = 0
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos/scanComponentSpec] componentSelector = 2
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos/scanComponentSpec] dcHuffTable = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos/scanComponentSpec] acHuffTable = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos/scanComponentSpec] componentSelector = 3
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos/scanComponentSpec] dcHuffTable = 1
  [/javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/sos/scanComponentSpec] acHuffTable = 1
Format 2 of 2 javax_imageio_1.0:
  [/javax_imageio_1.0/Chroma/ColorSpaceType] name = YCbCr
  [/javax_imageio_1.0/Chroma/NumChannels] value = 3
  [/javax_imageio_1.0/Compression/CompressionTypeName] value = JPEG
  [/javax_imageio_1.0/Compression/Lossless] value = FALSE
  [/javax_imageio_1.0/Compression/NumProgressiveScans] value = 1
  [/javax_imageio_1.0/Dimension/PixelAspectRatio] value = 1.0
  [/javax_imageio_1.0/Dimension/ImageOrientation] value = normal
```

Comment: The GPS info is stored in the Exif metadata of the file. In a "JPEG file", this is stored in the APP1 segment with an "Exif" identifier. The line `[javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0markerSequence/unknown] MarkerTag = 225` is probably the one you are looking for.  But there's no special support for this in the `IIOMetadata`, you need a custom or 3rd party Exif parser, like MetadataExtractor or similar.

Comment: Why would it need special support? Does the data come in a different format?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz Yes, the Exif data is stored inside the JPEG segment(s) as a TIFF stream. The data is all there, but you need to parse it to access individual fields of the Exif data.

Comment: TIFF? Isn't that an image format?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, with the help of josejuan and HaraldK, I've learned that the Exif data is there in the nodes I found, it's just shows up like this:

```
[javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0/markerSequence/unknown] MarkerTag = 225
```

If I cast this Node to an IIOMetadata node, I can call the `getUserObject()` method, which returns a byte array of 9444 bytes, which contains lots of data, including the GPS data. But the IIOMetadata API doesn't give me a way to parse all this data. That's why I need an outside library. The alternative would be, as josejuan pointed out, to write my own implementation of IIOMetadata. One day, the JPEGMetadata class may be revised to support this structure, but it's not there today.